# Numba parallel prange does not scale up - very slow

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, numba

I'm using Numba to speed up some number crunching code. The work is easily parallelizable, and I'm giving a try to numba.prange. I would expect almost a linear scaling with the number of threads (at least until memory bandiwth is reached) but I'm getting almost no scaling up.

I'm simply writing a Numpy array in slices, with each thread working on a different slice:

```
@numba.njit
def do_work(i_row_begin, i_row_end, out):
    a = np.empty(5)
    for i_row in range(i_row_begin, i_row_end):
        a[0] = i_row
        for index_s in range(out.shape[1]):
            a[1] = index_s
            for index_t in range(out.shape[2]):
                a[2] = index_t
                a[3] = index_t / (1.2 + i_row)
                a[4] = index_t / (1.8 + i_row)
                out[i_row, index_s, index_t] = np.sum(a / (1 + np.sum(a)))


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def do_work_parallel(num_threads, num_rows):

    out = np.empty((num_rows, 3, 300))

    # calculate threads
    num_rows_per_thread = int(math.ceil(num_rows / num_threads))

    for index_thread in numba.prange(num_threads):
        # Loop over loan parts
        i_row_begin = index_thread * num_rows_per_thread
        i_row_end = min(num_rows, (index_thread + 1) * num_rows_per_thread)

        do_work(i_row_begin, i_row_end, out)

    return out
```

And this is the 'main' script:

```
n_rows = 10000

def run(num_threads):
    return do_work_parallel(num_threads, n_rows)

# Execute function once to compile numba functions
_ = run(2)

for num_threads in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    print("Num threads", num_threads)
    now = time.time()
    _ = run(num_threads)
    diff = time.time() - now
    print("Time elapsed: {:.3e}".format(diff))
    print("Speed: {:.3e} rows/s/core".format(n_rows/(diff * num_threads)))
    print("")

print("DONE")
```

The output I get is the following:

```
Num threads: 1
Time elapsed: 1.078e+00
Speed: 9.275e+03 rows/s/core

Num threads: 2
Time elapsed: 1.484e+00
Speed: 3.368e+03 rows/s/core

Num threads: 3
Time elapsed: 1.442e+00
Speed: 2.311e+03 rows/s/core

Num threads: 4
Time elapsed: 1.469e+00
Speed: 1.702e+03 rows/s/core
```

So clearly there is no speed up at all. Actually parallelization is worsening the performance. Anyone can explain why this is happening?

Edit:
Seems related to this bug: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2699

Comment: What is read and write? It is almost impossible to answer a question only consisting of pseudo code. Can you give a short example on some real part of the problem?

Comment: I just edited the question and posted a simplified version of the code that can reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Just found it's related to this bug: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2699